# Where should I create my rails view - Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have a rails app whose homepage is as follows:

`www.person.com`

I then have a model - `Person` who has an `id` attribute.

If I want to create a view based on that ID, and I want the URL to look like this:

`www.person.com/{Person.id}`, or `www.person.com/1`

where should I create my view and what should I name it? Should it just be `Views/Person/index.html.erb?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather, create `show.html.erb` in `views/person(s)/`

You also need to create a controller method in `persons_controller.rb`:

```
def show
  # Insert options for person's page here
end
```

The magic happens in `routes.rb`, where you'll define the route for that `show`:

```
resources :persons, :path => '', :path_names => {:show => '/:id'}
```

Comment: Awesome - Being new to rails the explanation of all the pieces is helpful. Thanks.